# Entering words from input file into array

Tags: c, arrays, file, input

Hey guys so I am trying to take words from an input file and play around with them to put them in a certain order (which I believe I have done correctly).

My issue is that I do not think any of the words are actually going into the words array because as I print it nothing shows up. If I want to take the words from file and into the words array. What am I doing wrong?

```
        while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) == 1)
        {
            wc = strtok(word, " \n");
            while (wc != NULL)
            {
                wc = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                count++;
            }
```

Comment: check `strcpy(word, words[x])` here `words[x]` is unintialized

Comment: What are you trying to do here `wc = strtok(NULL, " \n");`?

Comment: I was just trying to count the number of words in the file so I could use the count variable @Vagish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) == 1)
```

I see that you are using `fscanf()` and `%s` so basically you are just fetching a single word from the file and later you are trying to break this word into tokens assuming you have fetched the line.

Use

```
char buf[100];
int count = 0;
while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf),file) != NULL)
{
   // Break the line into words using space as delimiter and copy it to the words array
   char *p = strtok(buf," ");
   while(p != NULL)
   {
      // strcpy(words[count],p); If you wish to copy the words into an array
      count ++;
      p = strtok(NULL," ");
   } 
}
printf("Number of words in the file are %d\n",count);
```

Comment: that used to be %99s should I change it back or try this?

Comment: @Jroc There are multiple bugs along with this.. While fetching each token you need to copy it into the array which I see you don't do

Comment: That is most likely my problem then. My mind is completely numb as this point though. So I am a bit confused on what to do to fix this @Gopi

Comment: @Jroc Check the edits to count the number of words in the file. Multiple checks needs to be added to make sure there is no array out of bound access.. I have given you the outline of how this can be done